# как взять элементы из log файла и вывести у них значения

Tags: php, файлы, post, email

Проблема следующая, реализовал передачу данных которые выбрал пользователь в массив, который мы следом передаем функцией

```
$мойМассив = array(0=>'test') (допустим)
file_put_contents('test.log', print_r($мойМассив, true), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Далее в другом файле у меня формируется отправка почты, где я беру этот массив таким условием:

```
if (empty(file_get_contents('./pages/test.log',true))) {
    $file = '';
} else {
    $file = file_get_contents('./pages/test.log',true);
}
```

и уже передаю его методами mail

```
if (!empty($_POST['tel'])) {
    $message = 'Телефон: '. $_POST['tel']. "\n\n" . 'Окно(а): ' . $file."\n\n";
} 
$send = mail('почта', 'описание', $message, 'заголовок');
```

по исходу у меня такое письмо:

```
Телефон: 312

Окно(а): Array
(
    [width] => 120
    [height] => 150
    [profile] => Econom
)
```

Мне необходимо чтобы выводил строки в виде:

```
Окно:
Ширина 120
высота 150
профиль Econom
```

P.S. не ругайте за говнокод, т.к. это основные вырезки без очевидных вещей.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr=array('width' => '120', 'height' => '150', 'profile' => 'Econom');
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {


    $newarr=array('width'=>'Ширина', 'height'=>'Высота', 'profile'=>'Профиль');

    $array[$newarr[$key]]=$value;

    echo $newarr[$key].'-'.$value.'<br>';
}
//или
print_r($array);
```

Comment: массив заполняется разными значениями, но ход мыслей я понял ) пробовать буду )) спасибо )

Comment: а может ли быть такой момент, что при file_get_contents мы получаем строковый тип и массив выводится как строка ?